# How to convert Object of class mysqli_result to String?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code:

```
$polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name); ...

... $result2 = mysqli_query($polaczenie, "SELECT money FROM roulette.users WHERE 
                                                        userSteamID='$SteamID'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
   print_r($row);
}
```

and I get this result: `Array ( [money] => 15 )`,

but I want this:  `var $money = 15`

How to convert Object of class mysqli_result to String?

I tried many options for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722375/object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-string-in) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352308/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-s).

Comment: `print_r($row->money);`

Comment: @iblamefish don't work

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_object() for fetching the result and then you can use $row->money;

Comment: Can you write code, please? becouse im new in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$money;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result2)){
   $money = $row->money;
}

echo $money;
```